# BLE scanning with handler

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process

I'm an Android developer beginner trying to develop an application as a CGM reader. Actually, I have my own device that can show the last glucose measure in its BLE services and I would like that my app connects and download glucose measurements every 60 seconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static int REQUEST_FINEACCESS_PERMISSION = 1;
    public final static String TIMER_CGM_NAME = "TIMER_CGM";
    public final static String TIMER_ALARMS_NAME = "TIMER_ALARMS";
    public final static int DELAYTOSTART_CGM_TIMER = 10000; //per avere il tempo di controllare tutti i permessi
    public final static int INTERVAL_CGM_TIMER = 300000;
    public final static int DELAYTOSTART_ALARM_TIMER = 10000; //attendi che qualcuno abbia fatto qualcosa
    public final static int TIM_REFRESH_GUI = 1000;
    public final static long TIM_GLUC_CATCH = 60000;
    public final static String PENDINGINTENT_CGM = "CGM_SERVICE";
    public final static int CGM_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public final static int CGM_INTENT_RESULT_FOUNDCODE = 200;
    public final static int CGM_INTENT_RESULT_NOTFOUNDCODE = 201;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_CGM_CONNESSO = 0xFFFE;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_CGM_SCONNESSO = 0x0001;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_POMPA_CONNESSA = 0xFFFD;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_POMPA_SCONNESSA = 0x0002;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_GLUC_NOBASSO = 0xFFFB;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_GLUC_BASSO = 0x0004;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_GLUC_NOALTO = 0xFFF7;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_GLUC_ALTO = 0x0008;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_IPOGLIC_EVENT = 0x0010;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_NOIPOGLIC_EVENT = 0xFFEF;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_IPERGLIC_EVENT = 0x0020;
    public final static int MASK_ALARM_NOIPERGLIC_EVENT = 0xFFDF;
    private static final String PRIMARY_NOTITFYCHANNEL_ID = "primary_notification_channel";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_GLUC_BASSO = 0;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_GLUC_ALTO = 1;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_IPOGLIC = 2;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_IPERGLIC = 3;

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
    private final String LIST_UUID = "UUID";

    public static final int  CMD_GETDATA    = 0x02;

    public static Context m_context;
    private SharedPreferences m_sharedPref;
    String m_username;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    volatile boolean mbBleEnableRequest = false;
    volatile boolean bCGMConnected = false;

    String mDeviceName;
    String mDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothLeService mCGMBluetoothLeService;
    private boolean mCGMConnected = false;
    private List<BluetoothGattService> mCGMGattServices;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> mCGMGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCGMNotifyCharacteristic;
    byte[] CGMWriteBytes = new byte[20];
    private String mCGMRxData;
    //

    TextView m_textview_username, m_textview_lastgluc, m_textview_allarmi, m_textview_insulina;
    AppCompatImageButton m_buttonImpostazioni, m_buttonBolo;
    Handler refreshHandler, glucCatchHandler;
    private Runnable runRefresh, runGlucCatch;
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertBuilder;

    ...

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        m_context = getApplicationContext();
        m_sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(m_context);

        //mi creo la mia classe singleton con la sua univocita'
        SingletonAssurance.initialize();
        String sCGMAddress = m_sharedPref.getString("CGM_address",getString(R.string.invalid_BLE_address));
        if(!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(sCGMAddress)) {
            bCGMConnected = false;
            SingletonAssurance.setIsPaused(true);
        }

        refreshHandler = new Handler();
        glucCatchHandler = new Handler();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //mbRunningTimer = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running_timer");
            //mUltimaAcquisizione = (MisuraGlucosio) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("last_misura");
            //mUltimaPredizione = (MisuraGlucosio) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("last_prediction");
        }

        m_username = m_sharedPref.getString("my_username", getResources().getString(R.string.default_username));
        m_textview_username = findViewById(R.id.textView_username);
        m_textview_username.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.main_welcome),m_username));
        m_textview_lastgluc = findViewById(R.id.main_ultimagluc);
        m_textview_lastgluc.setText("- - -");
        m_textview_allarmi = findViewById(R.id.main_allarmi);
        m_textview_allarmi.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.main_noalarms));
        m_textview_insulina = findViewById(R.id.main_insulinaattiva);

        mAlertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //richieste permessi bluetooth
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissionLauncherScan.launch(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN); //chiedere anche il CONNECT in cascata
            }
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] neededPermissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, neededPermissions, REQUEST_FINEACCESS_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            //non ci si dovrebbe passare mai, il manifest dovrebbe impedire installazione in dispositivi senza bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(m_context, R.string.error_BLE_notsupported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ForceCloseApp();
            return;
        }

        //gestione pulsante impostazioni
        m_buttonImpostazioni = findViewById(R.id.main_settings);
        m_buttonImpostazioni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(m_context, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //gestione pulsante bolo
        m_buttonBolo = findViewById(R.id.main_bolo);
        m_buttonBolo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        /*CGMTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(!mbBleEnableRequest)
                {
                    mbBleEnableRequest = true;
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        enableBLERequest_launcher.launch(enableBtIntent);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                Intent scanIntent = new Intent(m_context, BLEScanService.class);
                PendingIntent pendingResult = createPendingResult(CGM_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(), 0);
                scanIntent.putExtra(PENDINGINTENT_CGM,pendingResult);
                startService(scanIntent);
            }
        }, DELAYTOSTART_CGM_TIMER, INTERVAL_CGM_TIMER);*/

        /*AlarmsTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AggiornaGUI();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, INTERVAL_ALARM_TIMER);*/

        createNotificationChannel();

        runRefresh = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AggiornaGUI();
                refreshHandler.postDelayed(this,TIM_REFRESH_GUI);
            }
        };
        refreshHandler.post(runRefresh);

        if(!SingletonAssurance.isRunning())
        {
            SingletonAssurance.start(); //assicuro univocita'
            runGlucCatch = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!SingletonAssurance.getIsPaused())
                        catchNewGlucValue();
                    glucCatchHandler.postDelayed(this,TIM_GLUC_CATCH);
                }
            };
            glucCatchHandler.post(runGlucCatch);
        }

    }

    public void ForceCloseApp()
    {
        SingletonAssurance.stop();
        refreshHandler.removeCallbacks(runRefresh);
        glucCatchHandler.removeCallbacks(runGlucCatch);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        finishAffinity();
        onDestroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if ( requestCode == CGM_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE )
        {
            if( resultCode == CGM_INTENT_RESULT_FOUNDCODE) {
                //connettersi al CGM
                bCGMConnected = true;
                mDeviceName = data.getStringExtra("DEVICE_NAME");
                mDeviceAddress = data.getStringExtra("DEVICE_ADDRESS");
                Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(m_context, BluetoothLeService.class);
                bindService(gattServiceIntent, mCGMConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
            if( resultCode == CGM_INTENT_RESULT_NOTFOUNDCODE) {
                bCGMConnected = false;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private final ServiceConnection mCGMConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            mCGMBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (!mCGMBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                bCGMConnected=false;
                unbindService(mCGMConnection);
                mCGMBluetoothLeService = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            }
            else {
                // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
                mCGMBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                bCGMConnected=true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mCGMBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

    // Handles various events fired by the Service.
    // ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED: connected to a GATT server.
    // ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED: disconnected from a GATT server.
    // ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED: discovered GATT services.
    // ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE: received data from the device.  This can be a result of read
    //                        or notification operations.
    private final BroadcastReceiver mCGMGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mCGMConnected = true;
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mCGMConnected = false;
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
                mCGMGattServices = mCGMBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices();
                collectCGMGattCharacteristics();
                registerCGMListener();
                //Chiedi risultato 0
                RecallResults(0);
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                mCGMRxData=intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
                collectCGMData(mCGMRxData);
                //dato acquisito, concludi
                mCGMBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
                unbindService(mCGMConnection);
                mCGMBluetoothLeService = null;
                //elaboraMisureAttive();
            }
        }
    };

    private void collectCGMGattCharacteristics() {
        if (mCGMGattServices == null)
            return;

        String uuid = null;
        String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.dwn_unknown_service);
        String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.dwn_unknown_characteristic);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        mCGMGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

        // Loops through available GATT Services.
        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : mCGMGattServices) {
            HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
            currentServiceData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
            currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
            ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

            // Loops through available Characteristics.
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
                HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                currentCharaData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
                currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
                gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
            }
            mCGMGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
            gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
        }

    }

    private void registerCGMListener()
    {
        int charaProp = mCGMBluetoothLeService.DeviceUARTDataReq(); //McIn rende 16 = Notify, come deve essere per la caratteristica di lettura
        if(charaProp >-1){

            mCGMNotifyCharacteristic = mCGMBluetoothLeService.uartNotifyChar;
            mCGMBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mCGMBluetoothLeService.uartNotifyChar, true);

            byte[] value = new byte[20];
            value[0] = (byte) 0x00;
            mCGMNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(value[0], BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
            mCGMNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(CGMWriteBytes);

            mCGMBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(mCGMNotifyCharacteristic);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fail data Request");
        }
    }

    private void RecallResults(int numRec) {
        int charaProp = mCGMBluetoothLeService.writeDataRequestTodevice();
        if (charaProp > -1) {
            mCGMNotifyCharacteristic = mCGMBluetoothLeService.uartWriteChar;
            mCGMBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mCGMBluetoothLeService.uartWriteChar, true);

        }
        CGMWriteBytes[0] = (byte) 0x80;    //0
        CGMWriteBytes[1] = (byte) 0x0F;    //1
        CGMWriteBytes[2] = (byte) 0xF0;    //2

        int p=0;
        //              WriteBytes= hex2byte(data.toString().getBytes())
        CGMWriteBytes[3] = (byte) CMD_GETDATA;    //3
        CGMWriteBytes[4] = (byte) (numRec/256);
        CGMWriteBytes[5] = (byte) (numRec%256);
        for(p=6;p<20;p++)
            CGMWriteBytes[p] = (byte) 0x00;

        mCGMNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(CGMWriteBytes);
        mCGMBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(mCGMNotifyCharacteristic);

    }

    public static int[] hex2unsignedint(byte[] b) {
        if ((b.length % 2) != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong String");
        }
        int[] uscita = new int[b.length / 2];
        for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n += 2) {
            String item = new String(b, n, 2);
            uscita[n/2] = (int) Integer.parseInt(item, 16);
        }
        b = null;
        return uscita;
    }

    private static IntentFilter makeCGMGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        return intentFilter;
    }

    private void collectCGMData(String data) {
        if (data != null) {

            //byte[] values = new byte[20]; non possiamo gestire con byte, McIn rende unsigned, in java i byte sono signed
            int[] values = new int[20];
            int glucoseValue ;
            int idx = data.indexOf("80 0F F0");
            if(idx > 0)
            {
                String rcvData = data.substring(idx);
                String ComData = rcvData.replace(" ", "");
                //values = hex2byte(ComData.toString().getBytes() );
                values = hex2unsignedint(ComData.toString().getBytes());
                if(values[3]==CMD_GETDATA)
                {
                    int pos = 4;
                    int idxData = ((values[pos++] &0xFF) <<8) +(values[pos++] &0xFF);
                    if(idxData>=0)
                    {
                        Integer dataCodificata = Utility.CodificaData(2008+values[6],values[7],values[8],values[9],values[10]);
                        glucoseValue = ((values[13]&0xff)<<8)+(values[14]&0xff);
                        SingletonAssurance.setLastMisuraAcquisita(dataCodificata,glucoseValue);
                    }

                }
            }
            Log.d("readData","data:"+data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver, makeCGMGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        //Toast.makeText(m_context,"OnSTOP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        unregisterReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Toast.makeText(m_context,"OnDESTROY",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //unregisterReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    SpannableString formatLastGlucoseMeasure(String sData, String sMisura ,int iOutside)
    {
        String sToFormat = sData+"\n"+sMisura+" mg/dL";
        SpannableString sFormatted = new SpannableString(sToFormat);
        int inx=sToFormat.indexOf('\n');
        if(inx<0)
            return sFormatted; //precauzione piuttosto inutile
        int inx2=sToFormat.indexOf(' ',inx+1);
        if(inx2<0)
            return sFormatted; //precauzione piuttosto inutile
        sFormatted.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f),inx+1,inx2,0);
        if(iOutside>0)
            sFormatted.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),inx+1,inx2,0);

        return sFormatted;
    }

    public void AggiornaGUI()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void sendNotification(int type, String sTestoNotifica)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(type, sTestoNotifica);
        mNotifyManager.notify(type, notifyBuilder.build());
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(int type, String sTestoNotifica)
    {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, type, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        String titolo_notifica = "";
        switch(type)
        {
            case NOTIFICATION_GLUC_BASSO:
                titolo_notifica = m_context.getResources().getString(R.string.notifica_glucbasso);
                break;
            case NOTIFICATION_GLUC_ALTO:
                titolo_notifica = m_context.getResources().getString(R.string.notifica_glucalto);
                break;
            case NOTIFICATION_IPOGLIC:
                titolo_notifica = m_context.getResources().getString(R.string.notifica_event_ipo);
                break;
            case NOTIFICATION_IPERGLIC:
                titolo_notifica = m_context.getResources().getString(R.string.notifica_event_iper);
                break;
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_NOTITFYCHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(titolo_notifica)
                .setContentText(sTestoNotifica)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_glicemy_alert)
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        return notifyBuilder;
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> scanLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            String sCGMAddress = m_sharedPref.getString("CGM_address",getString(R.string.invalid_BLE_address));
            if(BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(sCGMAddress)) {
                SingletonAssurance.setIsPaused(false);
                bCGMConnected = true;
            }
            else {
                //rimani in pasua
                SingletonAssurance.setIsPaused(true);
                bCGMConnected = false;
            }
        }
    });

    public void openFindCGMActivity()
    {
        SingletonAssurance.setIsPaused(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(m_context, ScanForCGM.class);
        scanLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    public void openFindNewPumpActivity() {
        SingletonAssurance.setIsPaused(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(m_context, ScanPumpQRCode.class);
        scanLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    public void catchNewGlucValue() {
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(m_context, BLEScanService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingResult = createPendingResult(CGM_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(), 0);
        scanIntent.putExtra(PENDINGINTENT_CGM,pendingResult);
        startService(scanIntent);
    }

}
```

I already used BLEScanService and BluetoothLeService in another app which just download result (no problem to show code if you think is needed) in a dedicated activity, opened by FAB button.
I can see that app can connect to device (I see correct feedback from my device) but after this I have no further interaction between app and the device: it seems that the problem is that MainActivity does not receive serviceDiscovering broadcast from BluetoothLeService, as mCGMGattUpdateReceiver does not receive anything.
I think the problem is the interaction between mainActivity and Handler...can anyone give me suggestions or corrections for my code?

I tried to place registerReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver, makeCGMGattUpdateIntentFilter()); in different positions of the MainActivity code, but I got no result. I just had two or three success events in two days, but never able to repeat them.

****** EDIT 29/06/2023 ******
Actually I'm not sure if interaction problem are due to code or to phone/device coupling. Surely a big problem is that app is not catching value when it is in background, it seems scanIntent cannot work when in background. Since MAC address can be set as a preferences, executing a BLE scan in a separated window and choosing the device, code cab be simplified this way:

```
public void catchNewGlucValue() {
    mDeviceAddress = m_sharedPref.getString("CGM_address",getString(R.string.invalid_BLE_address));
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(m_context, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mCGMConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

In this way in background app can connect to device, but cannot complete operation to get measure

Comment: When you say you want to receive the measurement every 60s do you mean also when the app is in the background?

Comment: @Michael Kotzjan: yes, the app should receive measurements also when it is in background

Comment: Do your problems only occure once the app foes into background or also when in foreground?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan: actually, I think that my first problem was not depending from the code but from external cause, maybe problem between phone and glucose device. I restarted phone and it seems that registerReceiver is doing its job correctly. But I think you point the second problem of my app: it work only in foreground. When app is in background you have to take it in foreground to do the scheduled job, like handler is waiting foreground condition to work. Surely it depends on how implemented my app: any suggestion will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the correct way finally. Contrary to what I said in my previous answer, it is not good to connect directly to BluetoothLeService with the known MAC address. If the normal BLE Scan operation is done, things work really better, since if a measure catch fails because device is off, a new attempt is done regularly after 60 seconds. Regarding registerReceiver problems, they only appear if you stop application through red squared button of andorid studio. If app is closed in the normal way (sqaure button of the phone and swapped), next run works normally. So I modified MainActivity in this way:

```
public void catchNewGlucValue() {
    bCGMCatched = false;
    mDeviceAddress = m_sharedPref.getString("CGM_address",getString(R.string.invalid_BLE_address));
    //Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(m_context, BluetoothLeService.class);
    //bindService(gattServiceIntent, mCGMConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    if (mBluetoothLeScanner != null)
        scanMyCGM(true);
}

public void scanMyCGM(boolean start) {
    if(start) {
        scanCGMHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mBleScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCANCGM_TIME);

        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mBleScanCallback);
    }
    else
        mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mBleScanCallback);
}

private final ScanCallback mBleScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        BluetoothDevice aDevice = result.getDevice();
        if(aDevice != null)
        {
            if(aDevice.getAddress().equals(mDeviceAddress))
            {
                Log.i(BluetoothLeService.TAG,"Device scanned");
                scanMyCGM(false);
                Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(m_context, BluetoothLeService.class);
                bindService(gattServiceIntent, mCGMConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
        }

        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my code causing the problem of no measurement catch when app is in background: I was calling unregisterReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver) inside onStop overrided function, this obviously prevented correct functioning in background.
Surely, for correct background working, I should avoid to repeat BLE scan through PendingIntent and related service. Using directly BluetoothLeService on a known MAC address is good, probably because it is a binded service. I want to resume main part of my solution, maybe it's not the most orthodox, but could be good to catch data from BLE device every X seconds

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    m_context = getApplicationContext();
    m_sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(m_context);

    //mi creo la mia classe singleton con la sua univocita'
    SingletonAssurance.initialize();
    String sCGMAddress = m_sharedPref.getString("CGM_address",getString(R.string.invalid_BLE_address));
    if(!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(sCGMAddress)) {
        bCGMConnected = false;
        SingletonAssurance.setIsPaused(true);
    }

    refreshHandler = new Handler();
    glucCatchHandler = new Handler();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //mbRunningTimer = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running_timer");
        //mUltimaAcquisizione = (MisuraGlucosio) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("last_misura");
        //mUltimaPredizione = (MisuraGlucosio) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("last_prediction");
    }

    m_username = m_sharedPref.getString("my_username", getResources().getString(R.string.default_username));
    m_textview_username = findViewById(R.id.textView_username);
    m_textview_username.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.main_welcome),m_username));
    m_textview_lastgluc = findViewById(R.id.main_ultimagluc);
    m_textview_lastgluc.setText("- - -");
    m_textview_allarmi = findViewById(R.id.main_allarmi);
    m_textview_allarmi.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.main_noalarms));
    m_textview_insulina = findViewById(R.id.main_insulinaattiva);

    mAlertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //richieste permessi bluetooth
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissionLauncherScan.launch(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN); //chiedere anche il CONNECT in cascata
        }
    } else {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] neededPermissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, neededPermissions, REQUEST_FINEACCESS_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        //non ci si dovrebbe passare mai, il manifest dovrebbe impedire installazione in dispositivi senza bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(m_context, R.string.error_BLE_notsupported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ForceCloseApp();
        return;
    }

    //gestione pulsante impostazioni
    m_buttonImpostazioni = findViewById(R.id.main_settings);
    m_buttonImpostazioni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(m_context, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //gestione pulsante bolo
    m_buttonBolo = findViewById(R.id.main_bolo);
    m_buttonBolo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    createNotificationChannel();

    registerReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver, makeCGMGattUpdateIntentFilter());

    runRefresh = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AggiornaGUI();
            refreshHandler.postDelayed(this,TIM_REFRESH_GUI);
        }
    };
    refreshHandler.post(runRefresh);

    if(!SingletonAssurance.isRunning())
    {
        SingletonAssurance.start(); //assicuro univocita'
        runGlucCatch = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!SingletonAssurance.getIsPaused())
                    catchNewGlucValue();
                glucCatchHandler.postDelayed(this,TIM_GLUC_CATCH);
            }
        };
        glucCatchHandler.post(runGlucCatch);
    }

}

private final BroadcastReceiver mCGMGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(BluetoothLeService.TAG,"MAIN RECEIVE: "+action);
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mCGMConnected = true;
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mCGMConnected = false;
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
            //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            mCGMGattServices = mCGMBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices();
            collectCGMGattCharacteristics();
            registerCGMListener();
            //Chiedi risultato 0
            RecallResults(0);
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            mCGMRxData=intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
            collectCGMData(mCGMRxData);
            //dato acquisito, concludi
            mCGMBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
            unbindService(mCGMConnection);
            mCGMBluetoothLeService = null;
            //elaboraMisureAttive();
        }
    }
};

private void collectCGMGattCharacteristics() {
    if (mCGMGattServices == null)
        return;

    String uuid = null;
    String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.dwn_unknown_service);
    String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.dwn_unknown_characteristic);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    mCGMGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : mCGMGattServices) {
        HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
        currentServiceData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
        currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
        gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
        ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
            charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
            HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
        }
        mCGMGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
        gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
    }

}

private void registerCGMListener()
{
    int charaProp = mCGMBluetoothLeService.DeviceUARTDataReq(); //McIn rende 16 = Notify, come deve essere per la caratteristica di lettura
    if(charaProp >-1){

        mCGMNotifyCharacteristic = mCGMBluetoothLeService.uartNotifyChar;
        mCGMBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mCGMBluetoothLeService.uartNotifyChar, true);

        byte[] value = new byte[20];
        value[0] = (byte) 0x00;
        mCGMNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(value[0], BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        mCGMNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(CGMWriteBytes);

        mCGMBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(mCGMNotifyCharacteristic);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Fail data Request");
    }
}

 public void catchNewGlucValue() {
    mDeviceAddress = m_sharedPref.getString("CGM_address",getString(R.string.invalid_BLE_address));
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(m_context, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mCGMConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

registerReceiver(mCGMGattUpdateReceiver) can be placed inside onCreate, there is no need to override onStart and onStop. SingletonAssurance is used to share last measure between the handlers and have always correct GUI refresh

**EDIT 05/07/2023**
I still have two problems:

- If a connection event fail because device is off, after 60 seconds no new attempt is done
- Still present problem related to registerReceiver: it seems I need to use first a simpler app which collect all the results from the device and then start this app, otherwise registerReceiver do not catch anything (I can see this clearly through Logcat)

Any help would be really appreciated!